# How can move customer account navigation below market place navigation using before after?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I want to show customer account navigation before My webkul market place navigation. i am using before/after concept, but it is not working. I have used customer_account_navigation in before of marketplace code.

```
<customer_account>
     <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>marketplace/css/wk_block.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="core/template" name="marketplacenavigation" template="marketplace/navigation.phtml" before="customer_account_navigation" />
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```